# create a variable to replace variables in a model in R

Tags: r, model

When writing statistic model, I usually use a lot of co-variables to adjust the model, so I need to rewrite the variable again and again. Even though I could copy and paste, the model looks very long. Could I create a variable which could replace many variables? E.g.:

```
fm <- lm(y ~ a+b+c+d+e, data)
```

I could create a variable like: `model1 = a+b+c+d+e`, then the model looks like:

```
fm <-lm(y ~ model1, data)
```

I tried many ways, but it did successful, like `model1 <- c(a+b+c+d)`,

Could someone help me with this?

Comment: also consider `y~.`

Answer (score 2):

how about saving it as a formula?

```
model <- ~a+b+c+d
```

You can then extract the terms using `terms`, or update the formula using `update`

Example:

```
model <- mpg ~ disp + wt + cyl

lm(model, mtcars)
## Call:
## lm(formula = model, data = mtcars)
##
## Coefficients:
## (Intercept)         disp           wt          cyl  
##   41.107678     0.007473    -3.635677    -1.784944  

model <- update(model, ~. + qsec)
lm(model, mtcars)
## Call:
## lm(formula = model, data = mtcars)
##
## Coefficients:
## (Intercept)         disp           wt          cyl         qsec  
##    30.17771      0.01029     -4.55318     -1.24109      0.55277
```

Edit:
As Kristoffer Winther Balling mentioned in the comments, a cleverer way to do this is to save the formula as a string (e.g. `"mpg ~ disp + wt + cyl"`) and then use `as.formula`. You can then use familiar `paste` or other string manipulation functions to change the formula.

Comment: Or consider as.formula("~a+b+c+d"), then you can modify the formula by modifying a character string.